# Fear about Magento 2.0 as a developer

Tags: architecture

I've been working for the last two years as a Magento developer.I have learned some what of magento's folder structure, rewrite of classes, front end customization etc.

So if any requirement or customisation comes to me now i'm able to finish within deadlines. But suddenly I heard that magento 2.0 is a rewrite of the entire Magento (1) system.

So we need to learn from scratch on wards about the new system?

How much headache will it be to learn new system?

Of course new system will give better performance.

I will close this question asap if i get a little bit of an idea. Thoughts?

please don't down vote if this is not the right place.

Comment: It is too complex....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are changes in Magento 2 that will require new approaches to be learned, but it is not a complete rewrite. For example there are still modules, blocks, etc, but it does now use dependency injection and supports interception on methods to avoid class rewrites. The code is in github - Magento/magento2. There is some online docs too with a lot more to come. We do want to provide more guidance on best development practices to reduce upgrade pain for example. Magento 2 GA is not until late next year however. Lots more Magento 1.x work around until then (and for years beyond is my expectation).

Answer (score 8):

> So we need to learn from scratch onwards that system?
>   How much headache will give to learn new system?

Magento 2 has a lot of changes, but I think we will have a better start then the plain vanilla php developer.

But yes, there will be a lot what we have to learn.

> Off course new system will give better performance. any comments.

At the moment magento 2 is slower than magento 1 but I'm sure they will improve here a lot.